# ASP.NET SqlServer Session Replication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session

Curious whether folks have setup 2 way transactional replication on the tables ASP.NET uses for SqlServer stored session state (ASPStateTempSessions and ASPStateTempApplications) and the tables used for membership, role, and personalization?  How did it work out?  Were there any gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Membership, you are probably fine with Replication, alhtough a cluster might be better for scale. For state, I would be more inclined to use a cluster.

I would say the exception to this is when you have a geographically separated set of servers, but it is rare to have websites, except for some of the largest, geographically separated out.

Have I ever done replication on state or membership tables? no.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly you can do that, Just need to edit one of the stored procedure which has a small bug where you would end up with error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

to avoid this just change Stored Procedure **TempGetAppID**

from this

```
INSERT [YOURDBNAME].dbo.ASPStateTempApplications
            VALUES
            (@appId, @appName)
```

TO

```
INSERT [YOURDBNAME].dbo.ASPStateTempApplications
            (AppId,AppName)
            VALUES
            (@appId, @appName)
```